# Pairwise Test for Multiple comparisons (Nemenyi Test) in R

Tags: r, kruskal-wallis

I am using the package `PMCMR` to perform a postdoc Kruskal-Nemenyi test. 
When I run the test with the default settings:

```
posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test(x=coastal$HIGH_MORTGAGE, g=coastal$SIZECLASS, method="Tukey")
```

I get the following results and warning:

```
Pairwise comparisons using Tukey and Kramer (Nemenyi) test  
                   with Tukey-Dist approximation for independent samples

data:  coastal$HIGH_MORTGAGE and coastal$SIZECLASS 

       Large Medium
Medium 0.931 -     
Small  0.746 0.078 

P value adjustment method: none

Warning message:
In posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test.default(x = coastal$HIGH_MORTGAGE,  :
  Ties are present, p-values are not corrected.*
```

When I run the test changing the distribution to Chisq to apply a correction for the ties, I still get the same results and the chi-square distribution is not used.

```
posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test(x=coastal$HIGH_MORTGAGE, g=coastal$SIZECLASS, method="Chisq")

Pairwise comparisons using Tukey and Kramer (Nemenyi) test  
                   with Tukey-Dist approximation for independent samples

data:  coastal$HIGH_MORTGAGE and coastal$SIZECLASS

       Large Medium
Medium 0.931 -     
Small  0.746 0.078

P value adjustment method: none 

Warning message:
In posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test.default(x = coastal$HIGH_MORTGAGE,  :
  Ties are present, p-values are not corrected.
```

I would like to know if there is a bug in the package or if there is any methos I am not aware of to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

From version `PMCMR1.0` to `PMCMR1.1` (and `> 1.1`) the syntax has slightly changed, so it is `dist`, not `method`, it is:

```
posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test( x, g, dist = c("Tukey", "Chisquare"), ...)
```

or

```
posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test(formula, data, subset, na.action, dist =
 c("Tukey", "Chisquare"), ...)
```

The vignette that has included an example has been updated in version `PMCMR1.3` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very appreciated!